# HTML title attribute is not translated in Teams page when selecting a tag to browse

Tags: bug, tags, user-interface, stack-overflow-for-teams

While browsing the [Stack Moderators Team](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/), if I click on a tag (say [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)), the returned HTML contains:

```
<title>Newest &#39;72&#39; Questions - Stack Overflow - Stack Moderators</title>
```

which renders as:

```
Newest '72' Questions - Stack Overflow - Stack Moderators
```

instead of the expected:

```
Newest 'bug' Questions - Stack Overflow - Stack Moderators
```

This happens for any/all tags.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log in to the Team.
2. Click on the Tags link.
3. Click on any tag.

Comment: 72 is the ID of the [bug] tag on the Moderators team

Comment: I haven't tracked this regularly, but re-tested it just now and the behavior appears to be fixed.